# jquery menu going behind pdf loading in embed code

Tags: jquery, css, pdf, menu

I have drop down menu on the left and pdf on the right

```
<iframe visible="true" id="ipdf2" src="pdf/product.pdf" height="600" width="665" runat="server" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true"> </iframe>
```

When i mouse ver the menus it goes behind the pdf and it shows and hide when i mouse over the menu in Firefox and IE.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score -1):

```
.myMenu {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2; /* something higher than your iFrame */
}
iframe {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: One small problem the menu show and hides above the iframe pdf and fix for that?

Comment: You can see the page at:-

http://www.intelligaia.com/projects/pdf/product-features.html

Mouse over Wireless Lan

Comment: Wireless lan menu goes over the iframe in Chrome. What browser are you using that is having issues?